# Push docker image to ECR using CLI take too much time

Tags: amazon-web-services, docker, image, push, amazon-ecr

Situation: I'm trying to push a docker image to AWS ECR using the CLI, however, it takes more than 12 h due that the temporal AWS credential to do this expires before it is completed.

What I want to know:

- is there an alternative to having credentials that don't expiries, or can be used for longer?
- Can I split the images and upload them into parts?
- Do you have another solution or a resource that you think could be useful

Aditional information:

Internet speed upload: 2Mbps

Comment: Please read: [Can I ask only one question per post?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/222735/can-i-ask-only-one-question-per-post) --- While Stack Overflow does permit certain questions about Docker, we require that they (like all questions asked here) be specifically related to programming. This question does not appear to be specifically related to programming, but image management in a dedicated registry, which makes it off-topic here. You might be able to ask questions like this one on [sf] or [DevOps](https://devops.stackexchange.com/).

Comment: [Questions asking us to recommend or find a book, tool, software library, tutorial or other **off-site resource** are **off-topic** for Stack Overflow as they tend to attract opinionated answers and spam. Instead, describe the problem and what has been done so far to solve it.](https://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic)

Comment: As an aside: A quick calculation shows that with a 2 Mbps upload, one could upload 10800 MB or roughly 10.5 GB within 12 hours (`2 / 8 * 60 * 60 * 12 = 10800`). If we assume that only 25% of the upload bandwidth is used, This would mean that an image of ~2.5 GB should be transferrable within 12 hours. I would heavily recommend to make the image smaller if it is really that large.

Comment: Build the image on an EC2 server, or AWS CodeBuild, instead of on your local computer.